# Sharepoint OOTB HTTPHandler requests does not call response write method

Tags: sharepoint-2010, httphandler, httpmodule

When a request is being made for sharepoint ootb http handlers like calendarservice.ashx, the response write method within httpmodule didn't get called.
Like when changing the months with the arrow icons at top left in sharepoint 2010 calendar, it makes ajax call to following url

/_layouts/CalendarService.ashx

but when this request goes to my http module the response write method didn't get called, the write method get called for custom ashx pages but not for OOTB ashx pages
does any body have any idea on this behavior.